# Increase the size of sda1 on Debian 6 Linux

Tags: debian-squeeze, partition

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              10G  1.1G  8.4G  11% /
tmpfs                 983M     0  983M   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                   10M  140K  9.9M   2% /dev
tmpfs                 983M     0  983M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda2             914G  200M  868G   1% /home
```

I'm running Debian 6 and like to increase the size of sda1 with 600G from sda2. How do I accomplish this without messing up the partitions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a partition editor like `GParted` . It is capable of moving relevant filesystem data and resize the partitions accordingly.

Although it would be possible to run it from within the current installation, an easier way would be booting up a live CD.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend he uses the program while his linux is still running. The program will move content from one part of the hard drive's disk to another. This means some parts of the hard drive (that contain OS files) may get fragmented because they're currently in use.

Comment: gparted in general would not allow to move a partition with a mounted filesystem. You would need to pull some rabbits out of the hat in order to make it work from within a running system - it's doable, but using a Live CD is *so much easier*

Comment: I didn't know it was possible. Thanks for the information. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly; either you put more of your stuff inside `/home`, or you'll have to move all content from `/home` to `/home.tmp` on `sda1` to clear `sda2` and reinstall there.

I'm recommending a clean reinstall because `LVM` might help you in the future. Is this an option for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a physical access to the server you may try doing this with [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/). It's a free and OpenSource project that can re-partition Ext2/3/4, NTFS and many other file system formats.

What you should be aware is that you should be really careful when you're using the program. If your computer get's turned off (loss of electricity?) - you will probably get all of the information on the drive messed up. So you'll need to reinstall a fresh copy and start from zero.